# Network utilization data (DataReceived/sec, DataSent/sec) using "nettop" differs from Activity Monitor information

Tags: macos, terminal

I want to get network utilization data as shown by Activity Monitor > Network from command line.

I used `nettop -P -x -J bytes_in,bytes_out`, get data by 1 sec, and sum the total in and out.

But this value is different from the value that "Data received" and "Data sent" in Activity Monitor > Network displays.

It's possible to get correct "data received/sec", "data sent/sec" data?

[image]

---

result like this.

```
In              Out 
nettop  AM      nettop  AM             
2.66    3.3     0.411   1.4
2.03    8.18    1.47    4.32
4.16    1.82    0.8     0.767
3.94    3.12    0.85    1.34
13.49   11.1    0.1     2.16
```

Comment: Were your calculations (from nettop) dramatically different to Activity Monitor? Nothing says exactly what AM is calculating

Comment: @Gilby I update my result in the post, and yes I don't know what AM is calculating, maybe only choose it's believe the nettop?

Comment: I think you can believe both. But they may well be measuring different things. Where in the network stack is the measurement point - is it at the API calls by each process or is it at the network interface (and which one)? `man nettop` says it is at the socket level and traffic to/from all interfaces. I have various apps which measure network traffic - none of them agree.